# Como funciona a sintaxe de Tagged template strings: fn`texto ${10} texto`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Uma das novidades da ES6 são [*template strings*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
Como funciona essa nova sintaxe aplicada a funções?

Por exemplo, o que faz este código?

```
applyStyle `
  #minhaDiv {
    background-color: ${'#ccf'};
    width: ${50}px;
    height: ${40}px;
    font-size: ${10}px;
    padding: ${5}px;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 6):

*Template strings com marcações* (ou *tags*) são funções que recebem argumentos de maneira especial. Nas funções normais estamos habituados a uma sintaxe `minhaFn(a, b, c);` e depois, dentro da função, recebemos os argumentos que essas variáveis tinham no momento de invocar a função. Ou seja:

```js
const a = 50;
const b = 5;
const c = 'Km/h';

minhaFn(a, b, c);

function minhaFn(velocidade, tempo, unidade){
  const res = (velocidade / tempo) + unidade;
  console.log(res);
}
```

Com *tagged template string* os argumentos são distribuidos desta forma:

o primeiro argumento é uma array, com o texto da *template string*, e o segundo argumento e seguintes são as interpolações que a string recebeu.

**P:** O que são interpolações?
**R:** No caso desta template string `` `Olá ${nome}! Como estás?` ``, a variável `nome` faz uma interpolação à string, e será passada ao argumento 1 da função, e o resto do texto será passado em pedaços ao argumento 0 da função.

Exemplo:

```js
function saudacao(texto, pessoa){
  const frase = texto[0] + pessoa + texto[1]; 
  console.log(frase);
}

['Ana', 'João', 'Manuel'].forEach(nome => {
    saudacao`Olá ${nome}! Como estás?`
});
```

O exemplo da pergunta, com CSS, permite à função interagir com os argumentos caso seja necessário e reconfigurar esse CSS.

Exemplo:

```js
const style = document.querySelector('style');
const zoom = 5; // 5x

function applyStyle(css, ...valores) {
    valores = valores.map(x => typeof x == 'number' ? x * zoom : x);
    const rules = css.map((rule, i) => rule.concat(valores[i] || '')).join('');
    style.innerHTML = rules;
}

applyStyle `
  #minhaDiv {
    background-color: ${'#ccf'};
    width: ${50}px;
    height: ${40}px;
 font-size: ${10}px;
    padding: ${5}px;
  }
`;
```

```html
<style></style>
<div id="minhaDiv">Teste</div>
```

Comment: Que legal! Sabe me dizer se o Babel é capaz de traduzir para ECMA5 ou tagged template já é compatível com browsers antigos por padrão?

Comment: @LucasCosta tirando o IE já é compativel :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @LucasCosta sim o babel traduz, neste caso o exemplo ficaria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/bt4p82ec/

Comment: Isso me lembrou Lua ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @Phanpy interessante! Não conheço Lua, mas fiquei curioso agora :)