# O suporte a aspas invertidas em strings surgiu no EcmaScript 6?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

As aspas invertidas utilizadas em strings como  `` `exemplo` `` foram adicionadas no EcmaScript 6? Gostaria de saber se isso surgiu nessa versão.

PS: Não acredito que a pergunta seja duplicada, pois a minha dúvida é se a funcionalidade surgiu no EcmaScript 6 e não sobre o funcionamento dela e dos templates.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166954/como-funciona-a-sintaxe-de-tagged-template-strings-fntexto-10-texto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Gostaria de saber se isso surgiu nessa versão.

Conforme você pode encontrar na documentação sobre *[Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)* na MDN, sim, este recurso foi adicionado na especificação EcmaScript 6.