# Componentes em Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu li a documentação do Vue.JS e não entendi ao certo...

> O exemplo acima (e alguns outros futuramente) usa Template strings
>   para fazer templates de mais de uma linha mais legíveis.

Então toda vez que vou criar um componente vue tipo assim:

```
Vue.Component('nome-do-component', {

     template: 'Aqui vai todo meu html',

     data() {

         //...

     },

     props: ['title', 'content', 'font-search']

})
```

Então se eu tiver um html gigante vai tudo lá (no template), isso não acaba sujando o código?

Comment: Web Component  e string templates em Vue são perguntas bem diferentes... sugiro separar. Em relação a string templates não é mais que usar multi linhas para o código ficar mais legível. Em vez de ter um template longo numa linha só.

Comment: Parece que você está confundindo um pouco as coisas, a documentação usa a propriedade `template` para criar um componente porque os exemplos são curtos. Em uma aplicação real é mais provável que você use _Single File Components_, mas também pode serem usados as propriedades `template`, `el` e `render`. A citação que você colocou na sua pergunta apenas diz que vai usar [_String Templates_](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166954/6333) para que o código HTML fique mais legível, pois com _string templates_ você pode quebrar linha sem problemas. Não tem nenhum grande mistério.

Comment: Com o Sérgio mencionou, recomendo apagar a parte "Outra dúvida" da sua pergunta... Outra dúvida é outra pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O Vue.js utiliza o Virtual Dom para renderizar os componentes, então se você precisa ter 10 cards numa pagina por exemplo, é mais prático criar apenas **1** componente card e renderizar eles 10x usando apenas um componente base. Na prática isso poupa trabalho para o programador, deixa o código mais limpo e legível e torna a sua manutenção mais simples e no final das contas realmente, se você olhar seu código html no navegador, você verá o código html dos cards 10 vezes, pois ele renderizou as 10x na view.

Vou dar um exemplo em código:

Isso é o seu componente "card":

```
  <template>
     <div class="card">
        <h4 class="title">{{cardTitle}}</h4>
        <img :src="cardImageUrl" />
        <p class="text"> 
          {{cardDescription}}
        </p>
     </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        title: {
          required: true,
          type: String
        },
        description: {
          required: true,
          type: String
        },
        imgUrl: {
          required: false,
          type: String
        }
      },
      data () {
        return {
          cardTitle: this.title,
          cardDescription: this.description,
          cardimgUrl: this.imgUrl
        }
      }
    } 
  </script>
```

Com isso você tem um componente simples usando props, para utiliza-lo em outras páginas basta importa-lo dentro do  e instanciar ele nos components, assim:

```
<script>
  import card from '../sharedComponents/card';

  export default {
    components: {
     'my-card' : card,
    }
  },
</script>
```

e para usar o mesmo, use

```
<my-card :title="titulo card 1" :description="descrição card 1" :imgUrl="https://imagens/15163"></my-card>
```